# Python using method in class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write some code that will generate a list of lists of numbers. I just started learning about classes in python. I'm pretty sure this is something I can do but I guess I just don't understand what the question is asking me to do. So I'm supposed to have a private instance variable representing rows and columns of numbers (represented as a list of lists).

E.g. `board = SlidingPuzzle(3, 4)`

This should create the following list:

`[[0,1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6, 7],[8, 9, 10, 11]]`

```
class SlidingPuzzle:
    def __init__(self, numRows, numCols):
        self.__numRows = numRows
        self.__numCols = numCols

        outerList = []
        num = -1

        for i in range(__numRows):
            innerList = []
            for j in range(__numCols):
                num = num + 1
                list.append(num)
            outerList.append(innerList)

        return outerList
```

Comment: `list.append(num)` should be `innerList.append(num)`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: An `__init__` function shouldn't return anything. It should _store_ something to be used by later methods. For example, `self.squares = outerList`.

Comment: Also, why are you using double-underscore names like `__numRows`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem description specifically says:

> I'm supposed to have a private instance variable representing rows and columns of numbers (represented as a list of lists).

You're creating such a list, but you're not storing it in a private instance variable, you're trying to `return` it. You just need to change your last line from this:

```
return outerList
```

… to:

```
self._board = outerList
```

More generally: an `__init__` function never `return`s things. The caller is just writing `puzzle = SlidingPuzzle()`, so the only thing it gets back is your `self` instance, not anything you try to `return` to it. The point of `__init__` is to let you store values in attributes to be used by later methods. Which is why your assignment is asking you to do exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

So usually classes have methods like the initializer (`__init__(...)`) but the initializer shouldn't return anything (it's actually kind of returning the instance of this class) so I added another function `getrows()` which (I think) will do what you've tried. you should consider learning a little python - just google "learn python" and try a course you can do in your browser like [codecadamy](https://www.codecademy.com)

```
class SlidingPuzzle:
    def __init__(self, numRows, numCols):
        self.__numRows = numRows
        self.__numCols = numCols
        self._board = []
        outerList = []
        num = -1
    def get_rows_but_dont_return_them(self):
        for i in range(self.__numRows):
            innerList = []
            for j in range(self.__numCols):
                num = num + 1
                list.append(num)
            outerList.append(innerList)

        self._board = outerList
        # return outerList # uncomment this line to return the rows 
                         # which isn't in your question ;p
```

then try calling 
`foo = SlidingPuzzle()`
to initialize

Does this answer your question?

Comment: This is bad advice. The problem/assignment/whatever clearly specifies a sensible design—that `__init__` should the nested list in an instance variable. You're telling him to replace that with a different design that (a) doesn't meet the requirements, and (b) isn't as useful. Why?

Comment: Now there's an `__init__` method that leaves the board empty, and a `getrows` method that doesn't actually get the rows but does mutate the internal storage. Imagine using a class with this interface.

Comment: @abarnert haha that would be a nightmare! now the interface makes sense...

Comment: @StevenBlack  So can I pass arguments to SlidingPuzzle just like I do with functions? I imported the python file to my linux shell and then tried callling SlidingPuzzle(3,4). It says "name 'SlidingPuzzle' is not defined"